# Whats the best way to remove a property from nested javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, javascript-objects

I have a tree object as below, I am trying to remove the items array property if it's empty. I am not sure on the best approach to do this?

I am thinking of looping through the key, check the property and then remove using `delete myJSONObject[prop]`... Any thoughts / ideas are welcome?

```
[{
    text: "TreeRoot",
    items: [{
        text: "Subgroup1",
        items: []
    }, {
        text: "Subgroup2",
        items: []
    }, {
        text: "Subgroup3",
        items: [],
        items: [{
            text: "subgroup5",
            items: [{
                text: "subgroup6",
                items: [{
                    text: "subgroup7",
                    items: [{
                        text: "subgroup8",
                        items: []
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: I would build a new object, rather than trying to modify this one.

Comment: Hey, you solved this yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446426/how-do-you-recursively-remove-nested-objects-that-contain-an-empty-array

Answer (score 5):

This should do the job (**ES5**):

```
function removeEmpty(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    (key === 'items' && obj[key].length === 0) && delete obj[key] ||
    (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(obj[key])
  });
  return obj;
};
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/huxeti/edit?html,js,console)

Same in **ES6**:

```
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
    (key === 'items' && obj[key].length === 0) && delete obj[key] ||
    (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(obj[key])
  );
  return obj;
};
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/fesoko/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 1):

You can have recursive algorithm that at each step either removes `items` array and returns, or recursively processes each individual object of the array.

I would also try to do this on the server-side. It will save a lot of complexity, memory, and processing time. There are usually ways of "excluding" empty arrays from the JSON encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ text: 'TreeRoot', items: [{ text: 'Subgroup1', items: [] }, { text: 'Subgroup2', items: [] }, { text: 'Subgroup3', items: [{ text: 'subgroup5', items: [{ text: 'subgroup6', items: [{ text: 'subgroup7', items: [{ text: 'subgroup8', items: [] }] }] }] }] }] }];

const modify = (obj) => objectScan(['**.items'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) {
      delete parent[property];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj);

console.log(modify(data)); // returns number of deletions
// => 3
console.log(data);
// => [ { text: 'TreeRoot', items: [ { text: 'Subgroup1' }, { text: 'Subgroup2' }, { text: 'Subgroup3', items: [ { text: 'subgroup5', items: [ { text: 'subgroup6', items: [ { text: 'subgroup7', items: [ { text: 'subgroup8' } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

This old question has been brought back up, and I think modern JS works well with recursion to yield a simple answer to do this in an immutable way:

```js
const removeEmptyItems = (xs) =>
   xs .map (({items = [], ... rest}) => ({
    ... rest, 
    ... (items .length ? {items: removeEmptyItems(items)} : {})
  }))

const tree = [{text: "TreeRoot", items: [{text: "Subgroup1", items: []}, {text: "Subgroup2", items: []}, {text: "Subgroup3",items: [{text: "subgroup5", items: [{text: "subgroup6", items: [{text: "subgroup7", items: [{text: "subgroup8", items: []}]}]}]}]}]}]

console .log (removeEmptyItems (tree))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This function simply maps over the array, keeping the rest of each object, and for its `items` property, skipping it when it's empty and recurring when it's not.

I've got to say, when the question was first asked, this answer would have looked quite foreign!  Now it's just normal JS!

Answer (score 0):

This is my (probably not perfect) TypeScript with Generics solution.

It tries to infer first level keyof - maybe some more advanced Guru may help :)

```js
type MyObject = { [index: string]: unknown };

export function removeProperties<T extends MyObject, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, propsToRemove: K[]): Omit<T, K> {
  if (!obj) {
    return obj;
  }

  const newObj = { ...obj } as MyObject;
  Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    const value = obj[key] as any;

    if (propsToRemove.includes(key as K)) {
      delete newObj[key];
    } else if (typeof value === 'object' && value != null) {
      newObj[key] = removeProperties(value, propsToRemove);
    }
  });
  return newObj as Omit<T, K>;
}
```