# Recursively remove object which contains empty array in nest json object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to dynamically delete json object which contains empty array. I've found this link [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9446426/3606247). But it doesn't work for me in my case.

Suppose I have a JSON object:

```
{"op":"1","parameters":[{"op":"2-1","parameters":[]},{"op":"2-2","parameters":[1,2]}]}
```

I've wrote a sample code to do the stuff recursively:

```
function removeEmptyArray(cJSON){
    if(!cJSON)
        return cJSON;

    for(var i=cJSON.parameters.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(!(cJSON.parameters[i].parameters instanceof Array))
            continue;
        if(cJSON.parameters[i].parameters.length==0){
            cJSON.parameters.splice(i,1);
        }else{
            cJSON.parameters[i] = removeEmptyArray(cJSON.parameters[i]);
        }
    }
    return cJSON;

}
```

the expect result is `{"op":"1","parameters":[{"op":"2-2","parameters":[1,2]}]}`, the code works fine.

but when I have this obj:

```
{"op":"1","parameters":[{"op":"2-1","parameters":[{"op":"3-1","parameters":[]}]},{"op":"2-2","parameters":[1,2,3]}]}
```

The output is `{"op":"1","parameters":[{"op":"2-1","parameters":[]},{"op":"2-2","parameters":[1,2,3]}]}`

Obviously it does not dynamically remove the json obj whose "op" is "2-1".

So how to solve it in an elegant way, using pure javascript?

Comment: what is the possible depth of your structure? is it indefinite? Are you trying to implement tree-like structure

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Rouz the depth is unknow but it's not infinite.

Comment: @Sunson So can there be elements on the same level? If you remove one node, what should happen with children nodes?

Comment: @Rouz If I remove one node, only because it has no children nodes, that is, the array is empty. The example is already given in the question

Comment: @Andreas More hints please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [breadth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algoritm, which look first in the depth and then deletes, if necessary.

```js
function isNotEmpty(object) {
    if (Array.isArray(object.parameters)) {
        object.parameters = object.parameters.filter(isNotEmpty);
        return object.parameters.length;
    }
    return true;
}

var object = { "op": "1", "parameters": [{ "op": "2-1", "parameters": [{ "op": "3-1", "parameters": [] }] }, { "op": "2-2", "parameters": [1, 2, 3] }] };

isNotEmpty(object);
console.log(object);
```